# Google Analytics for Mobile App - without SDK

Tags: android, ios, mobile, google-analytics, cocoonjs

I would like to track screen views for my mobile app in Google Analytics without using the iOS or Android SDKs. My App is HTML5 wrapped in Cocoon.io. Having access to AJAX already, I make HTTP calls directly. I do see the pixel GET is getting called with all the proper fields and a 200 as response. But there is no data in GA.

Has anyone tried this? Is it even possible? Any ideas on how to properly debug this?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  I can POST from mobile to the API and get a 200 back from GA, but nothing in the reports.  I can run the same POST in Fiddler with the same user-agent as mobile app and it will show in the reports.